# How to disable sound in my app only?

Tags: android, performance

How can i disable all sounds in my android app only.
Other application's sounds should be running.
I can disable sounds by using ,

```
AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager)getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
audioManager.setStreamMute(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, false);
```

But it will disable all sounds of whole mobile/tablet.I just want to disable my app's sound.

Comment: since is your app, can't you just avoid emitting sound?

Comment: Shouldn't you just be able to not play sound?

Comment: but when user wants to listen songs in music player & play my puzzle game.Than he must be able to disable my game's sound.i want to provide this facility.

Comment: does your game play background music or just short game effects?

Comment: @Shruti: You could provide a menu item on your game's screen that specifies whether the sound is on or off. If you structured your code properly then a change like this should be trivial. You definitely don't need to depend on the system to manage your app's audio.

Comment: @paul how can i do it ?

Comment: @lelloman it's endless background music..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Finally i found answer for my own question.
I just muted all sounds when user presses the mute button by,

```
media.setVolume(0,0);
```

and set it 1 to enable it....

Comment: +1 There you go! Would you mind expanding on your answer a little? I.E. provide a link to the Droid API you used, the exact call to enable volume (you mention using 1 but there are two params to the method). Thanks!

Comment: both parameters should be 1 for enabling volume.
these parameters stands for left & right speaker volume.
    media.setVolume(leftVolume , rightVolume);
both are float values , lies between 0 to 1.